# Cant find out why my C code is not working

Tags: c

Here is my C code that aims to make a linked list of n element ""n is read from keyboard"" building is 100% successful but when executing an error message appears and the program stops working.

```
typedef struct maillon* ptr;

struct maillon {
   int vale;
   ptr adr;
};

ptr Allouer( ptr p )
{
   return malloc( sizeof(struct maillon) );
}

void Aff_val( ptr p, int v )
{
   p->vale= v;
}

void Aff_adr( ptr p, ptr q )
{
   p->adr = q;
}

void main()
{
   ptr debut, courant, fin;
   int n, vale;
   scanf("%d",&n);
   Allouer(debut);
   Aff_val(debut,5);   //5 is a value that contains my 1st element 
   courant=debut;
   for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
   {
      Allouer(fin);
      Aff_adr(courant,fin);
      printf("enter the value");
      scanf("%d",&vale);
      Aff_val(fin,vale);

      courant=fin;
   }
   Aff_adr(courant,NULL);
}
```

Comment: And what might the error message be? Tried debugging?

Comment: Building is not 100% successful. In fact, the compiler generates 3 warnings. If you aren't seeing the warnings, then use `-Wall` with gcc or clang, or `/W4` with microsoft. If the compiler generated the warnings, and you ignored them, then you're just being ...

Comment: le programme a céssé de fonctionner

Comment: what is the purpose of the function Allouer? You pass a parameter to it, but you're not using it!

Comment: yes i've rectificate this one but still not working . in fact i'm little bit lost betweens differents answers !!!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the line

```
Allouer(debut);
```

The value returned from `Allouer` is not used. Not only do you not see `debut` set to a valid pointer but also the program suffers from a memory leak. Change it to:

```
debut = Allouer(debut);
```

---

Suggestion for further improvement.

`Allouer` does not use the input argument. It will be better to remove it.

```
ptr Allouer()
{
   return malloc( sizeof(struct maillon) );
}
```

Then, it's usage can be changed to:

```
debut = Allouer();
```

Comment: I don't know who teaches that convention. It's terrible. It definitely makes code less readable.

Comment: Really my question too - I never saw any decent book saying it.

Comment: You are 100% right but I would suggest. `void Allouer( ptr p )
{
   p = malloc( sizeof(struct maillon) );
}` instead of returning the pointer, this is slicker when because you initiate 2 variables first time in main `ptr debut` than in `Allower` when you return address from malloc.

Comment: @GRC, for that to work, you'll have to use `void Allouer( ptr* p ) { *p = malloc( sizeof(struct maillon) ); }` and then use it with `Allouer(&debut);`. Not my preference.

Comment: @RSahu you are right :), wrote that comment on the fly, however I would go with pointers instead of returning a pointer.

Comment: void Allouer( ptr* p )

{
     *p=malloc( sizeof(struct maillon) );